# Laravel - how to write form action for post comment

Tags: forms, laravel, url

To post a comment write form action like this

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('posts/{{$post->id}}/comments') }}">

                 {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label>Comment *</label>
                                <textarea maxlength="5000" rows="10" class="form-control" name="body" id="body" placeholder="here will be your comment"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="submit" value="Post Comment" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-loading-text="Loading...">
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </form>
```

and route code is

```
Route::post('posts/{post}/comments','CommentController@store');
```

but prob is when it shows error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')' (View: 
the showing error line is

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('posts/{{$post->id}}/comments') }}">
```

so where is my mistake in this line? how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just use blade directives in another blade directive, you have to concatenate the variable in the string. Like so:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('posts/' . $post->id . '/comments') }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line to:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('posts/'.$post->id.'/comments') }}">
```